# How to calculate the correlation length from the (connected or disconnected) correaltion function?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, phase-transition

Here, "[How to determine correlation length when the correlation function decays as a power law?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/334837/how-to-determine-correlation-length-when-the-correlation-function-decays-as-a-po)" has a similar question, and Adam gave a good answer. However, I don't know how to derive the computational formula of correlation length, can anyone give me some literature about it?

Comment: That formula can be taken to be the definition of “correlation length”. If you don’t like it, what’s your definition?